# How to check the form completeness in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can we check the **table** completeness in rails? I have a model called **User** which contains around 45 fields.

Currently I am using the following logic to check the **User** completeness. How can we optimise this logic. Is there any better way to check this thing?

```
def user_completeness?
 if (user.name.present? && user.dob.present? && user.email.present etc.,)
  true
else
 false 
end
```

end

Comment: Use validation for that.

Comment: 45 fields? Oh my!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the `.valid?` method.

I'd recommend reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html and implementing validations in your model.

I hope this helps!

Ben